# Hibernate: Commiting MariaDB via JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jersey, mariadb, jersey-test-framework

Im trying to write a small application which should offer a restful interface. This at it's own works together with the current hibernate-version relatively good.

When trying to test, my serverside code for modifying like this:

```
EntityManager manager = // [...]
manager.getTransaction.begin();
AEntity entity1 = manager.find(AEntity.class, 4711);

entity1.setSomething("whatever");
manager.merge(entity1);

manager.getTransaction.commit();
manager.close();
```

Normally this should work. But when testing with JUnit it does not.

```
EntityManager manager = // [...]
// insert some test data

Response r1 = target(url).request().put(someAEntityChangeInfo);
assertEquals(200, r1.getStatus());
manager.refresh(mAEntity);
assertEquals("whatever", mAEntity.getSomething()); // was set and commited on server-side
```

The last assert fails saying that `mAEntity` (which should be updated) contains the old data. I'm also not sure whether this behaviour may be a race condition, since once (but only once) the assert was okay.

**How to make sure that data got really commited before asserting?**

*Using MariaDB, MariaDB Connector/J, Hibernate 5.0.7 and Jersey 2.22.1.*

Comment: why are you starting a transaction, calling flush and committing it when there is nothing in the transaction?!

Comment: I need to sync the "cache" of the EntityManager. For normal use, i open one EntityManager at the server side. For verifying written data, i need a second EntityManager in my Test. Without flushing (with itself is only possible in transaction) at Test-side the Entites would refresh with old data. At least i thought so. Am i wrong?

Comment: An empty transaction is going to do nothing, and a flush is done within commit anyway so that line is of no value as well. There is no "syncing" to be done (not that the L1 cache will ever "sync" anything). I don't see the relation between the first transaction and the second in your post either

Comment: OK. I removed it, without effect. I want to check the entity changed on server-side in my test, but it still contains (after refresh) the old data. In database, there is also the old data -> the commit on server-side seems to do nothing on database (but it should write the changes).

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be a mix of flushing transactions and connection isolation.

To resolve this:

- Set the flush-mode to commit: `manager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);`
- Set connection isolation for testing to `READ_COMMITED` so that the test-connection is able to see the changes made by tested code with another EntityManager. For production a higher isolation my be better. JPA-property: `<property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="2" />`

There is also hibernate's `autocommit` property. Set to `false` for keeping more control about the behaviour.